# Prestashop: Add modules to custom hook for future updates

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop, updates

Is it possible to add custom hook to a module in prestashop so it stays there after module update?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about core modules, there a trick to do that.

Let's assume that you want to add custom hook "MyCustomHook" for "blockcontactinfos" core module.

```
class Module extends ModuleCore
{
    public function hookMyCustomHook($params)
    {
        if ($this->name != 'blockcontactinfos')
            return;
        return 'Here it is's!';
    }
}
```

Comment: override\classes\module\Module.php

Answer (score 0):

You can don't add new hook and use {hook h="[nameHook]" mod="[namemodule]"} in template files.

Sample: `{hook h="displayTop" mod="blocksearch"}` - this code display a content generated by blokseacrh for displayTop hook in place, where you using it